# Dropdown and filter event

Tags: angular, filter, primeng

This concerns the Dropdown component from PrimeNG.
I would like to send a request when something is typed in the filter (not the select, the filter of the suggestions). But it seems there is no event binded to the filter... And I can't find how to template my own filter (to make a ngModel or something like that).
Is there a solution ? Thank you.

Comment: im also interested